# Regex to find and remove Abbreviations which are either ABC or A.B.C

Tags: python, regex

In my data, there are lot of garbage things like `IIT-JEE`, `AIPMT`, `C.B.S.E.`. So I came to a regex to remove these by using `(?<!\w)([A-Za-z])\.` . It is removing `C.B.S.E.` **BUT** it is also removing `x.y` which is part of the useful equation.

So Basically I want to remove Abbreviations of length more than 2 so that **lower case** `x.y` is preserved but **Upper Case** `X.Y.Z.` is removed. Also I want to remove any words which are Upper Case and are of length>=3. Such as `abc` is preserved but `IIT` is removed.

What can I do to modify my existing regex or how can I make a new one to fulfil these tasks?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> So Basically I want to remove Abbreviations of length more than 2 so that lower case `x.y` is preserved but Upper Case `X.Y.Z.` is removed. Also I want to remove any words which are Upper Case and are of `length>=3`. Such as `abc` is preserved but `IIT` is removed.

You may try this regex:

```
\b(?:[A-Z]{3,}\b|(?:[A-Za-z]\.){2,})\s*
```

[RegEx Demo](https://regex101.com/r/6KD770/2)

**RegEx Details:**

- `\b`: Word boundary
- `(?:`: Start a non capture group

  - `[A-Z]{3,}\b`: Match a word of 3+ uppercase letters
  - `|`: OR
  - `(?:[A-Za-z]\.){2,}`: Match an abbreviation of letter followed by dot of min length=2
- `)`: non capture group
- `\s*`: Match 0 or more whitespaces

Answer (score 3):

You could use

```
(?<!\S)(?:(?:[A-Za-z]\.){3,}|[A-Z]{3,})(?!\S)
```

**Explanation**

- `(?<!\S)` A whitespace boundary to the left
- `(?:` Non capture group

  - `(?:[A-Za-z]\.){3,}` Repeat 3 or more times A-Za-z followed by a dot
  - `|` Or
  - `[A-Z]{3,}` Match 3 uppercase chars
- `)` Close non capture group
- `(?!\S)` A whitespace boundary to the right

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/rnSsn5/1)

Comment: It is working fine but there is ust a small problem. It is completely discarding `A.I.P.M.T`. Yo see the missing dot in the end. If only we could remove up until, `AIPM`, I could remove every single character in my data. You getting my point? More than two words like  remove `a.b.c`, `a.b.c.`  and `a.b. c` (with dot) but not `a.b c` (without dot)?

Comment: @Deshwal Like this? `(?<!\S)(?:[A-Za-z](?:\.\s*[A-Za-z]){2,}\s*\.?|[A-Z]{3,})(?!\S)`  https://regex101.com/r/zsq0xV/1